# Batch Script: Path with space with double quotes does not work?

Tags: batch-file

Here are the codes in a .cmd file:

```
@echo off 
start "title" /b /wait "%~dp0bat file.cmd" 
pause
```

When I place it in a directory path containing space and run it, the console returns "The system cannot find the file specified." Of course I also put the "bat file.cmd" there.
What am I missing please?

Comment: try `start "title" /b /wait cmd /c "%~dp0bat file.cmd"` or `start "title" /b /wait cmd /c ^""%~dp0bat file.cmd" ^"`

Comment: Try `Call "%~dp0bat file.cmd"`

Comment: can't replicate. Try with `echo on` to see, what's really executed.

Comment: My bad. The error was in the "bat file.cmd", there was a wrong path in it. Thank you all.